# Как исправить ошибку Android Studio «No server to serve request»?

Tags: android-studio

**Система**: Xubuntu 18.04 32-bit.
В логах ничего нету. Просто на этапе Make Project "Run Tasks" появляется эта ошибка. Java 8 (SDK/JRE) установлена и настроена.
Полный текст ошибки: "*Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, дело было в том, что система 32-битная. Переустановил на 64-битную, и всё заработало.